# Bar code scanner page navigation issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I have this tutorial for bar code reader/scanner that I followed. In `ScannerPage`, when I click a button it will open the `scanner` and after reading, it will pass the result to the database using API and the return to `ScannerPage`.
I am having this error `Page must not already have a parent` but I dont know why. How can solve this?

```
private async  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => 
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async() => 
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
                //send something using WEB API
            });
        };
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are pushing scanPage twice

```
    scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

    // this is not needed
    // await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => 
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async() => 
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            //send something using WEB API
        });
    };

    // navigate here, AFTER you have defined your OnScanResult handler
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
```

Comment: The error is gone but the problem now is it's not going back to `ScannerPage`. Thank you by the way. I appreciated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are `await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);` twice.

Change it to:

```
private async  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => 
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async() => 
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            //send something using WEB API
        });
    };
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it's not coming back to `ScannerPage`.

Comment: Not sure if that's the same question then ;-) ... does the `scanPage` show? And if so, does the `OnScanResult` fires?

Comment: Oh sorry. Thank you so much

Comment: No, thank you :-) But does it work? If you have a follow-up question, let me know.

Comment: Yes, `scanPage` shows and the `OnScanResult` fires but the problem is it is not navigating back to the the `ScannerPage`.

Comment: And `ScannerPage` is the page before `scanPage`?

Comment: Btw; it's defenitly worth another question: you'll attract more people to answer your question faster only because it's new and fresh :-)

Comment: Yes, It has the `Button` to open the `scanPage`

Comment: I'd like to ask more but I think it's my limit already so I can't ask more. :/

Comment: Hmm... it's a pretty common navigation structure you have here, so it should work. If you set a breakpoint at `await Navigation.PopAsync();` does that hit?

Comment: If the `scanPage` has a `Navigation` property, maybe you need that one. Otherwise check if your `MainPage` is a navigation page (which I think it is, but otherwise I am blank)

Comment: Yes, it does. Tried it just now and yes it's a navigation page

Comment: Keep me posted... meanwhile, I really need to get some sleep. Good luck for now.